# How to use Cordova with Crosswalk and having cookies

Tags: cordova, cookies, cordova-plugins, crosswalk-runtime

I'm really struggling with Cordova and Crosswalk. I managed to setup the project, it works, but I'm having issues with cookies.

If I understand correctly, when using `file://` protocol, the Crosswalk Webview Engine does not use cookies. Ok, then, I enabled the use of cookies by setting `setAcceptFileSchemeCookies(true)` .

However, this does not work. Let's assume my API is at api.example.com , and the API is configured to set the domain for the cookies to `.api.example.com` . These cookies do not show up in my application.

The application loads the local index.html . I could configure it to load the files from a remote website, like `www.example.com` , but how can I load local resources? I believe I cannot load a local image/css/js, when cordova loads a remote URL.

So I'm pretty stuck and I have no idea how to fix this, or why the cookies don't work. And no, I cannot change the use of cookies.

Comment: You can use XWalkCookieManager directly. First try something like this:
`XWalkCookieManager mXCookieManager = new XWalkCookieManager();
mXCookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
mXCookieManager.setAcceptFileSchemeCookies(true);`

If cookies are not saved, you can try to save them manually. Something like this:
`mXCookieManager.setCookie(".api.example.com", "coookie=1");`

Comment: @tehmaestro What version of crosswalk are you using? check this out  - https://crosswalk-project.org/jira/browse/XWALK-4643